# Readonly css attribute not working

Tags: html, css, readonly

```html
<form action="javascript:goCalc('calcForm')" id="calcForm" name="calcForm">
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr bgcolor="#bfd5ea">
        <td style="font-size: 30px; color: f00; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-ALIGN: center">
          Donation:</td>
        <td style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-ALIGN: center">
          Tax Rate %:</td>
        <td style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-ALIGN: center">
          Net Cost of Donation</td>
        <td style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; color: 00f; TEXT-ALIGN: center">
          Tax Savings</td>
      </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#e6eef7">
        <td align="middle" nowrap="nowrap" valign="center">
          $
          <input class="formtext" name="inputIncome" size="12">x</td>
        <td align="middle" bgcolor="#e6eef7" nowrap="nowrap" valign="center">
          <select class="formtext" id="inputPercentage" name="inputPercentage">
            <option selected="selected" value="10">10%</option>
            <option value="15">15%</option>
            <option value="25">25%</option>
            <option value="28">28%</option>
            <option value="33">33%</option>
            <option value="35">35%</option>
            <option value="39.6">39.6%</option>
          </select>=</td>
        <td align="middle" valign="center">
          $ <span style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-ALIGN: center"> <input class="formtext" id="inputCost" name="inputCost" readonly="readonly" size="12"> </span>
        </td>
        <td align="middle" valign="center">
          $
          <input class="formtext" id="inputMoney" name="inputMoney" readonly="readonly" size="12">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="right">
        <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="center">
          &nbsp;</td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="center">
          <div align="center">
            <input class="btn" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Calculate">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="center">
          <div align="center">
            &nbsp;</div>
        </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="center">
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Issue is when user clicks the calculate tab, it does not display the other fields as coded... Tried everything, please help - (2) Readonly lines issue - in lower section of code - only need to display attributes of amount

Comment: Where is your `goCalc()` javascript function?

Comment: There's a lot of this within the site I am building this for, but I need to make this calculator work without the js (independently operating) since I need to add to the mobile app I'm building for it... Do you have any suggestions on how I can just make it work, so the output is the correct total when user enters amount??

Comment: thanks for the update.. I figured out you were right about the javascript missing... theres a lot of code to this and had to add part of this in at the end..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `cursor-events`attribute on an inline css? Say

```
        #inputMoney{
            cursor-events: none;
        }
```

or you can also try using the `disabled='disabled'` property though you have to enable thhose disabled elements before you submit the form

Comment: thanks... I didn't consider that...  I'm so desperate for a solution, until it doesn't even matter if the answer amounts are ready only... At this point I just need the calculator to work - producing the correct digits - thank you for the assistance

Comment: I just tried this.... can you please provide an example using the code line above, so I can see more clearly what you're suggesting please...

Comment: If you make fields `readonly` instead of `disabled`, then you can still read their values.

Comment: @TrudyJordan, here's a simple example on making an element behave like an element with a `read-only` attribute:   `<input class="formtext" id="inputMoney" name="inputMoney" style='pointer-events:none'>` You can also replace the `style` property of the element to `disabled='disabled'` though it is not advisable to use the `disabled` property if the value of that element is going to be submitted. Or maybe you can also consider displaying the value by assigning it on a "display only" tags like `<span>` or `<p>` instead of using textboxes..

Comment: I just tried all suggested variations of it, and no luck... even with changing the tags... thank you very much for the updates, if you have any and I do mean any other suggestions, then please share, please

Comment: I finally figured it out... my code is kinda complex for this javascript - so I ended up having to go through the entire site and seen that part of the js needed to readded to at the end of this one -- THANKS SO MUCH for the assistance.. thank you and have a blessed day.. tried to paste it but too for pasting option.. thank you

Comment: You're welcome @TrudyJordan, though I haven't really solved your problem haha. Too bad you can't put here what you did to make it work, it would be great for other users having the same problems. Have a nice day

Comment: awwwwwww... now I feel bad... sorry :-)  here's the answer in parts.. hope this helps all users; for this one, semi-complex coding... enjoy **Instructions (place this code AFTER the code I posted as a question... PART 1 >> <script type="text/javascript">
  function goCalc(formname)
  {
  if(document.forms[formname].inputIncome.value != "") // && !(isNaN(document.forms[formname].inputIncome.value)))
    {
    var income = document.forms[formname].inputIncome.value;
  var percentage = document.forms[formname].inputPercentage.value;
  var cost;
  var savings;

Comment: PART 2>>  //take out commas and dollar signs ** MODIFIED 07/14/2015  by TJ - Fixed to work properly
    income=income.replace(/\$/g,'');
  income=income.replace(/,/g,'');
    //calculate value
    savings = Math.round(parseInt(income) * parseInt(percentage)) * 0.01;
    cost = Math.round(parseInt(income) * (100-parseInt(percentage))) * 0.01;  
    // give both values a proper money format and put it in form field
    document.forms[formname].inputMoney.value = outputMoney(savings);
  document.forms[formname].inputCost.value = outputMoney(cost);
  // document.forms[formname].inputIncome.value

Comment: PART 3>>  = outputMoney(document.forms[formname].inputIncome.value);
    }
  }
  function outputMoney(number) {
    return outputDollars(Math.floor(number-0) + '') + outputCents(number - 0);
}

function outputDollars(number) {
    if (number.length <= 3)
        return (number == '' ? '0' : number);
    else {
        var mod = number.length%3;
        var output = (mod == 0 ? '' : (number.substring(0,mod)));
        for (i=0 ; i < Math.floor(number.length/3) ; i++) {
            if ((mod ==0) && (i ==0))
                output+= number.substring(mod+3*i,mod+3*i+3);
            else

Comment: PART 4>>  output+= ',' + number.substring(mod+3*i,mod+3*i+3);
        }
        return (output);
    }
}
function outputCents(amount) {
    amount = Math.round( ( (amount) - Math.floor(amount) ) *100);
    return (amount < 10 ? '.0' + amount : '.' + amount);
}

Comment: **if you're copy and pasting... remember that after each answer/comment I've posted, there's a dash then my name, do not include the dash; otherwise the code will not work properly :-)